# Visual C# OleDbException was unhandled?

Tags: database, ms-access

Good day Im having a problem after dragging the dataset into my windows form. I am using MSACCESS for my database and whenever i run it. "OleDbException was unhandled", An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll/' will appear

```
private void Admin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.usersDBTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDBDataSet.UsersDB); <-- Problem
            }
```

Comment: So handle the exception and see what the error is so you can correct it?  The keywords you're looking for are `try` and `catch`.

Comment: Ok thank you, ill work for it..